# Can I have 2 subversions servers on the same computer?

Tags: svn

I have one Ubuntu server currently running SVN with one repository with the svn+ssh:// protocol, so my users have shell access as well, I want to install another instance of SVN but only with protocol svn:// or http:// so new users  DON'T have access to shell nor the original repository, they will have another different repository.

If I do this, could the new svn server cause any conflicts with the original svn server ??

Note: I don't know if this is relevant but in the same computer there's a shell that downloads the java source code from svn, compiles it and deploy it in a tomcat server in that same computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want your users having shell access? [The Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks) has a lot of interesting configuration tricks.

Can you have multiple repositories using Subversion `svnserve`? Yes as long as they all run under a single `svnserve` instance, or you use different ports for each `svnserve` instance running.

Otherwise, you might want to look into using Apache `httpd` as your Subversion server. It offers a lot more flexibility and is much easier to configure with LDAP permissions. Windows Active Directory can be exposed as a LDAP service which means that your Windows login becomes your Subversion login. Firewalls are also less likely to block Port 80 or Port 433 (https). It's why httpd access, although slower than svn, is used so frequently.

Answer (score 1):

If there are running on different port number you can have multiple svn servers on the same machine.  But you might want to use just one server and create multiple repositories instead.